# Reauthorizing facebook application

Tags: php, facebook, authorization

I'm developing a facebook application and everything is going fine with log in and comments etc.

I came across the issue of 'reauthorizing' users. One of my users 'accidentally' pressed 'don't allow' when it asked them for access to their information and now they cannot sign in.

Does anyone know how I can reauthorize them?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
It turns out that once I officially published the application the users' error disappeared. I'm pretty sure you aren't supposed to have work-in-progress published apps but that certainly solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should ask for permissions automatically. Try to tell him to do this:

1. Go to **My account > Privacy** settings
   (I don't know the exact text of the
   option because mine is in spanish).
2. Then, in the footer menu, select
   **Applications and Web sites**
3. Next to **Applications that you use**,
   click on **Edit settings**
4. Search your app and delete it.
5. Re-enter in your app and permissions dialog should appear.

Comment: Thank you, I've forwarded the information. Will let you know how they get on tomorrow!

Comment: Okay, sorry for not getting back sooner - the joys of waiting for user test results.

Although your solutions make sense and should work, apparently my site is not listed at all in their privacy settings?

Edit

Must the application be 'published' before any of this can be done properly? At the moment it is a work in progress piece.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by manuelpedrera previously, after the user remove the application from their facebook account, he / she has to re-access your website and retry to login to your website using their facebook account. Once they choose to allow the permission, your app will again be added under their facebook account and everything should be back to normal. good luck mate :-)

Comment: Hi, no-one got back to me so thought I would repost in your response. The user doesn't have the app listed in their settings, do you know of any other methods to re-access my website? Thank you

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if this will work. You can try to open the following url: http://www.facebook.com/developers. You will find the list of applications on the right side, select "See my apps" link, then select your application and edit the setting for that particular application. Update me if this works.

Comment: Hi, it turns out that once I officially published the application the users' error disappeared. I'm pretty sure you aren't supposed to have work-in-progress published apps but that certainly solved my problem. Thank you for your help.